# Are there "close" solutions to Hilbert's third problem?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polyhedra, dissection

[Hilbert's third problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem) (or a modern formulation thereof) asks whether two polyhedra $P,Q$ of equal volume are equidecomposable by cutting $P$ into finitely many polyhedral pieces and rearranging them to obtain $Q$. (In the two-dimensional case, [this can always be done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem) with polygons of equal area.)

With the use of [Dehn invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant), one can show that this is impossible; however, the proof focuses on specific equivalence classes of dihedral angles, and does not seem to rule out "approximate" solutions.

To be more precise: Given polyhedra $P,Q$ of identical volume, here are some notions of a "close" solution to Hilbert's third problem:

- For all $\epsilon>0$, $P$ may be cut into finitely many polyhedra which can be reassembled to form a polyhedron which contains a copy of $Q$ scaled down by $1-\epsilon$ and is contained in a copy of $Q$ scaled up by $1+\epsilon$.
- For all $\epsilon>0$, $P$ may be cut into finitely many polyhedra which can be reassembled to form a polyhedron whose boundary differs from that of $Q$ over a region of surface area less than $\epsilon$.
- For all $\epsilon>0$ and points $x$ on the boundary of $Q$, $P$ may be cut into finitely many polyhedra which can be reassembled to form a polyhedron which is identical to $Q$ except within a ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$.

The first condition is easily satisfied by chopping up $P$ into very very small cubes; I do not see how to show the latter two conditions, though I expect they are probably true. **Is it known whether dissections meeting the latter two conditions can always be performed?**

Comment: For the second variant, how do you define the difference of boundaries, precisely?

Comment: @lisyarus: The total surface area of that portion of the boundary of $P$ which is not also part of the boundary of $Q$, and vice versa. For each face of either polyhedron, we add the surface area of those parts of the face which do not overlap a face of the other polyhedron in the same plane. As an example, if $P$ were the cube $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $Q$ the box given by $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,2]$, there would be $6$ square units of area over which the boundaries differed: $1$ on $P$ but not $Q$, and $5$ on $Q$ but not $P$.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Thus you consider what is called the "symmatric difference" of $Q$ and its approximating set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference